# JSPM can't install (404 from github) BUT CAN install from npm

Tags: javascript, github, npm, jspm

This is truly frustrating.

Package.json for a repo hosted on **github** as part of my organisation. I am trying to pull this in via jspm.

```
{
  "name": "tf-modernizr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "modernizr.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr.git"
  },
  "author": "Simon Douglas",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr#readme",
  "directories": {}
}
```

**npm install works fine** (!!!)

running jspm install:
`jspm install github:tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr@master`
or `jspm install github:tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr` informs me there is a 404.

```
 Looking up github:tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr
 Updating registry cache...
 Downloading github:tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr@master
 warn Error on download for github:tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr
 Bad response code 404
 err  Error downloading github:tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr.
```

The documentation here http://jspm.io/docs/getting-started.html doesn't help. The documentation here https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm is complex. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try going to the repo? It doesn't exist: https://github.com/tomorrowfinance/tf-modernizr

Comment: I made it public, and JSPM is happy. It have to look into making JSPM work with private repos. This doesn't really answer the question though, although it does resolve my problem :/

Comment: If it's a private repo, @Simon, you have to add git credentials

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a private repository, you need to allow jspm to access it.

Simply configure access to github using: `jspm registry config github`